# Visual Studio Code Debugger freezes

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

After i press F10 on VS Code, he runes a random number of lines (maximum 10) and something is loading non-stop and i have to restart vs code to try again to debug. I looked after settings for this but i didn't found anything.

I run python with VS Code

[Video of what i am trying to say](https://youtu.be/Gl8CRY28KEw)

Comment: Does this happen with other python scripts that are known to be good?  If not, then it is your script.  Stack smash, buffer overrun, blocked UI thread, deadlock, some other code problem.

Comment: Honesly, i don't know how to respond to this. Probably the scripts that are known to be good, because i just installed anaconda3 and vs code, and i runned a notebook with vs code. I say 'just installed' because i reinstalled my windows and i have 2 hours from installing vs code and python and having this issue. I had this issue before

Comment: really does installing VSC and Python 2 hours? Try to delete Anaconda and just use the Python from `python.org`

Comment: looked at the video and did do any purpose of showing your problem